# How to pass a parameterised method to a Struts 2 action's method attribute?

Tags: java, configuration, struts2, ognl

I'm going to do search data from database using `like` expression. My method looks like this:

```
public List<Item> getData(String qString){
   return itemJpa.getSuggestedData(qString);
}
```

My purpose is when I input a query string to the `qString` variable, I need to get the data in the list. I'm doing this using Struts2. I need to map this method to the struts action's method attribute. Such as

```
<action name="DummyDB" class="com.shopping.op.welcome.DummyDB" method="**In Here**"></action>
```

Is it possible? If it is how can I do this?

Comment: can you be a bit more clear as what exactly you want? or may be I am not able to understand your question

Comment: In my index page has a search box. It is working as a autocomplete drop down. When I press a enter, I need to view the all data from database(I used like expression).

Comment: So, what is your issue ? like where you are getting strucked?

Comment: Data is not viewing..

Comment: how you are submitting form? and you can always point method name in your jsp action configuration or even can use method name in your XML file

Comment: In jsp action I forward to DummyDB class. In this class has a method, such as getData(String qString). I need to call this method when i call this action..

Comment: Do you want to pass the user input to the user to struts action method or specify the action method to be invoked in struts.xml. Your question is quite unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't map an action to a method that has parameters in signature, or return result other than `String`. What can you do is create another method for example `doData()`

```
private List<Item> data;
//getter and setter

public String doData() {
  data = getData(qString);
  ...
  return Action.SUCCESS;
}

<action name="DummyDB" class="com.shopping.op.welcome.DummyDB" method="doData">
 <result>/jsp/whateveryoudo.jsp</result>
</action>
```

In addition to it you need to know that a class you mapped to the action should be a qualified java bean which have a default no-arg constructor or doesn't have constructors at all (in this case the implicit default constructor is used). Struts will instantiate the bean when you make a request to the action mapped by this action config. So, to get it able to do you should follow these simple rules.